# How to detect currently opened swf filename

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript

I want to detect currently opened swf file name. Here is my code:

```
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
  ListWins "*.swf*"
End Sub

Sub ListWins(Optional Title = "*", Optional Class = "*")
  Dim hWndThis As Long

  hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)

  While hWndThis
    Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
    sTitle = Space$(255)
    sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))

    sClass = Space$(255)
    sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))

    If sTitle Like Title And sClass Like Class Then
      Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
      List1.AddItem (sTitle)
    End If

    hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
  Wend
End Sub
```

This code is working fine to detect `*.doc`, `*.xls` files name, but not working on `*.swf` files.

Comment: Oh god, hideous code!!! (now formatted nicely)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**

I have tested it in VBA. I am sure it will work in VB6 as well.

Try this (**Paste this code in a module and run the Sub Sample**)

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal HWnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextA" (ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Public Function APIWindowCaption(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Static winnum As Integer
    Dim MyStr As String

    winnum = winnum + 1

    MyStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(HWnd) + 1, Chr$(0))

    GetWindowText HWnd, MyStr, Len(MyStr)

    '~~> This will give you the caption of the window
    If InStr(1, MyStr, ".swf", vbTextCompare) Then Debug.Print MyStr

    APIWindowCaption = 1
End Function

Sub Sample()
    Dim retval As Long, DesktophWnd As Long

    DesktophWnd = GetDesktopWindow

    retval = EnumChildWindows(DesktophWnd, AddressOf APIWindowCaption, ByVal 0&)
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: thank u very much to your support this code show only swf player name but not show swf file name i need to get current swf file name please check it again

Comment: Do you mean like `Example.swf`?

Comment: yes u r i need to get example.swf but this code show swfplayer not example.swf

Comment: Where have you opened the swf file? Also can you share the snapshot of the window which has the swf opened?

Comment: swf player name is    SWF & FLV Player

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11264/discussion-between-user757321-and-siddharth-rout)